# Successful ajax script doesn't give me response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

The general problem is that I cannot get back echo or return through ajax from another file.The alert(msg) is empty. Does that prevent.default stop sending the GET? I am not very fluent in programming, could you please help me in this?

I have my simple form:

```
<form class='findAndBlock1' method="GET" action="">
    <input type='text' name="nameToBlock1" placeholder="    who do you want to block?" class='nameInput'>
    <input type='submit' value="Search" class='submitInput1'>
</form>
```

After clicking it, the ajax script starts:

```
<script>
$(".submitInput1").click(function(){

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/searchFriendsToBlock",
        data: {

        },
        success : function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        },
        error : function(error) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });   
});
</script>
```

It is directed to the script that is routed like this:

```
Route::any('/searchFriendsToBlock', 'SettingsController@searchFriendsToBlock');
```

Here is the script that is run through ajax:

```
   public function searchFriendsToBlock() {

        $q = Input::get('nameToBlock');
        if (strlen($q) < 3)
            return null;

        $users = DB::table('users')->where //here goes some long request

        foreach ($users as $user) {

            if (!$user->f_first_name_public)
                $user->first_name = "";
            if (!$user->f_last_name_public)
                $user->last_name = "";

            $user->avatar = User::getUserAvatar($user->id);
            $user->id = "";
            $user->type = "user";
            $newArr[] = $user;
        }
        echo "hello";
        return Response::json($newArr);
    }
```

Comment: your preventDefault is not working anyway.add event in like `function(event)` please do console.log(msg)

Comment: @Pekka That's true on FF which doesn't use global event model, so ya, OP should pass `event` as handler callback parameter

Comment: @Pekka This prevent.default makes the form not refresh my page. Okay i am checking the console.log now

Comment: @WantToBeProgrammer Is the event bound at least? Debug it and see. Error in console (network one)?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a success?

Comment: @A.Wolff No errors in network. Is the event bound? I am not really sure what I should do with it.

Comment: @Amarnasan Yes, it is success, only empty alert

Comment: @aldrin27 it gives me "undefined" in alert

Comment: @WantToBeProgrammer i have added Answer please check

Comment: Add Datatype: 'json'

Comment: Please also remove the echo. Ajax wont be Apple to decode the json string.

Comment: @mimo Okay, thank you and guys above. I am getting "null" now. No idea why but something happens finally :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dataType` parameter in ajax request as you are sending response in `json` format the default `dataType` is set to `html` in `jQuery.ajax()`

```
<script>
    $(".submitInput1").click(function(){

        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/searchFriendsToBlock",
            data: {

            },
            success : function(msg) {
                alert(msg.type);
            },
            error : function(error) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

And Your script should be like this

```
public function searchFriendsToBlock() 
{                                  
    $q = Input::get('nameToBlock'); 
    if (strlen($q) < 3)
        return null;

    $users = DB::table('users')->where //here goes some long request
    $response  = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if (!$user->f_first_name_public)
            $user->first_name = "";
        if (!$user->f_last_name_public)
            $user->last_name = "";

        $user->avatar = User::getUserAvatar($user->id);
        $user->id = "";
        $user->type = "user";
        $newArr[] = $user;
    }
    $response['type'] = 'sussess';    
    $response['data'] = $newArr;    
    return Response::json($response);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After adding dataType I see "null" alert. And this .keyInJson (should I actually add it too? console says its something undefined). Damn programming is difficult >.>

Comment: @WantToBeProgrammer it should be your key in response

Comment: Okay thank you. Looks like it works now but the answer is null right? Does that mean something is still wrong?

Comment: @WantToBeProgrammer i have updated code please check

Comment: if it is not working try with echo Response::json($response); instead of 
return Response::json($response);

Comment: Thank you for still helping me :) I have already tried echo, print, vardumps etc but its still "null". Maybe the prevent.default stops the GET sending? it actually makes it is not added to the link hmm

Comment: @WantToBeProgrammer let me know your result after update

Comment: I checked the update, but it shows "null" :X . And when i add .type it shows that i cannot get type of null. Why always me CRY haha

Comment: open console and check what you are getting in response

Comment: In network i clicked on "SearchFriendsToBlock" and i see below "this request has no response data available"

Comment: now debug your searchFriendsToBlock() to check it is actual called or not by echo 123;die;at first line and check console

Comment: Adding this echo at the first line of my function shows "123" in alert. Console see 123 too. Oh man I'm not sure what that means but I'm sure that I owe you a huge beer for that help :D

Comment: The problem is caused by this string length part. No idea how to fix it yet, but deleting it made my script work! :)